# SwiftUI : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when define data type

Tags: api, swiftui, graphql

This warning is really weird to me because I was able to create one of the data type but the other 2 are not. You will see the implement + init are mostly the same.

1 small question, if my graphql API does not have id, which is the best way to implement the id? I'm currently use country name for id. which I think is a pretty bad practice

Thank you in advance!

```
typealias CountryData = ScpecificCountryQuery.Data

struct Countries: Decodable {
    var countries: [Country]

    init(_ countries: CountryData?) {
        self.countries = countries?.countries.map({ country -> Country in
            Country(country)
        }) ?? []
    }

    struct Country: Identifiable, Decodable {
        var id: String {
            return currency
        }

        var code: String
        var name: String
        var phone: String
        var capital: String
        var currency : String
        var continent: Continent ( Does not have any warning)
        var languages : Lan  ("Type of expression is ambiguous without more context")
        var states: State   ("Type of expression is ambiguous without more context")

        init(_ country: ScpecificCountryQuery.Data.Country?) {
            self.name = country?.name ?? ""
            self.code = country?.code ?? ""
            self.phone = country?.phone ?? ""
            self.capital = country?.capital ?? ""
            self.currency = country?.currency ?? ""
            self.emoji = country?.emoji ?? ""
            self.continent = Continent(country?.continent)
            self.languages = Lan(country?.languages)
            self.states = State(country?.states)
        }
        
        struct Lan: Decodable {
            var code: String
            var name: String
            
            init(_ lan: ScpecificCountryQuery.Data.Country.Language?) {
                self.code = lan?.code ?? ""
                self.name = lan?.name ?? ""
            }
        }

        struct Continent: Decodable {
            var code: String
            var name: String

            init (_ continent: ScpecificCountryQuery.Data.Country.Continent?) {
                self.code = continent?.code ?? ""
                self.name = continent?.name ?? ""
            }
        }

        struct State {
            var code: String
            var name: String

            init (_ state: ScpecificCountryQuery.Data.Country.State?) {
                self.code = state?.code ?? ""
                self.name = state?.name ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One immediate thing that jumps to mind is that `State` is not conforming to `Decodable` - might solve your issue. Try to make is into a reproducible example, not requiring people to stub out the missing types, like `ScpecificCountryQuery` in order to reproduce the error you're seeing.

Comment: thank you @NewDev But it still not working :(

Comment: It was a shot in the dark. Again - create a reproducible standalone example.